# Is $\mathbb{Z} [(-2)^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ ever a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

Let $n>2$ be an integer.

Consider the integral domains $\mathbb{Z} [(-2)^{\frac{1}{n}}]$.

For what integer values of $n$ is  $\mathbb{Z} [(-2)^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ a UFD ?

Are there infinitely many solutions ?

Same question for $\mathbb{Z} [2^{\frac{1}{n}}]$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}\left[\left(-2\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right]$? Because $\mathbb{Z}\left(\left(-2\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$ is defined to be a field containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\left(-2\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, and so is always a UFD.

Comment: Im new to ring theory , what is The difference between those 2 brackets ? For instance what is The difference between Z(sqrt(2)) and Z[sqrt(2)] ?? Sorry. Also I mentioned integral domain , so it is integrally closed. I assume that the square brackets imply integrally closed and the other round brackets just extended without closure.

Comment: If $R\subseteq S$ are rings with $s\in S\backslash R$, then $R[s]$ is the smallest subring of $S$ containing $R$ and $s$, whilst $R(s)$ is the smallest such subfield (if one exists, with slight abuse of notation because $S$ is not assumed to be a field). Where here the terminology “smallest” subring / (subfield) means the intersection of all possible such subrings / (subfields)

Comment: So for example $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ does not contain $\frac{\sqrt{2}{2}$ whilst $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$ does.

Comment: I think The square brackets. Fractions are not a part of what i meant.

Comment: I did not understand that reuns. Im new to ring theory

Comment: For $n \le 10,K=\mathbb{Q}((-2)^{1/n})$ [magma tells](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) me $O_K$ is a PID (class number $1$) thus a UFD. It also tells me $O_K = \mathbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/n}]$. If you had $O_K $ larger than $\mathbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/n}]=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x)),f(x) = x^n+2$ then you'd need to find how $O_K,\mathbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/n}]$ are different from $O_K[Disc(f)^{-1}]=\mathbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/n},Disc(f)^{-1}]$

Comment: What is “ disc “ ? Discriminant ?